# How to recover `/usr/lib/jvm` in Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, files

I accidentally deleted `/usr/lib/jvm` through the terminal.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 19):

First let's see which package(s) provided the files in that directory:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/jvm
openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64, default-jre-headless: /usr/lib/jvm
```

(please check on your own system - the exact packages may be different)

Then reinstall those packages (replace with your own results):

```
sudo apt install --reinstall openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 default-jre-headless
```

Now `/usr/lib/jvm` is back